# Getting data from table in a modal by checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having trouble inserting data from a table in a modal div into the table element where I want to display the content based on the data selected by the checkbox when I click the "Add" button.

Here is my code:

Modal's table code:

---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="mod_search" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Members</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <table class="table table-hover table-managed">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Speciality</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM `personal_profile`";
                        $sql_run = mysql_query($sql_search);
                        while($m = mysql_fetch_array($sql_run))
                        {

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="member_select[]"></td>
                            <td><?php echo @$m['lastname'].', '.@$m['firstname'].' '.@$m['middlename'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo @$m['speciality'];?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add_button" id="button_add">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Table of selected data code:

---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

            <table class="table table-managed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Speciality</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    $sql_select="SELECT * FROM `event_attendees` WHERE `id`='".@$_REQUEST['member_select']."'";
                    $sql_run=mysql_query($sql_select);

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_run))
                    {

                    }
                    ?>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="name_row"></td>
                    <td id="speciality_row"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Hope you can help me. I've been looking on the internet but nothing was exactly related to my issue.

Here are the images:

The 1st image is the modal that displays when you click "Search" if the "Member" radio button is selected from the original page (2nd image).

[image: Modal]
[image]

Comment: Now, Post Images. Ok. Got 10 Reputation.

Comment: *post edited* Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand your question. Which image is first? first one or second one ? Sorry

Comment: I'm sorry. The first image is the modal. The second one is the table of selected data.

Comment: which button you click from the second image to get that popup modal

Comment: When you click the radio button of "Member", the textboxes will be disabled and the "Search" button will appear. When you click the button the modal will display. I'll post a new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it. :)

```
//set the function
$("#add_button").click(function(){

/* check for your table where to send the data from the current table then
use the selector for the checkboxes when clicked */
    $('#table_select input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){

        var getRow = $(this).parents('tr'); //variable for the entire row
        var value = (getRow.find('td:eq(2)').html()); //data for names
        var value1 = (getRow.find('td:eq(3)').html()); //data for specialty
        var value3 = (getRow.find('td:eq(1)').html()); //data for prc


        $('#attendee_table tr:last').append('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prc[' + attendees_id + ']" id="prc" value="' + value3 + '" readonly></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + value + '" id="names" name="name[' + attendees_id + ']" readonly></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + value1 + '" id="specialties" name="specialty[' + attendees_id + ']" readonly></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="delete_btn1[' + attendees_id + ']" id="delete_btn1" data-id="' + attendees_id + '" onclick="deleteMem(this)" value="Delete"></td></tr>');
      /* then append your row (include the variables to the value of the textboxes. 
I use textboxes for it may able to save the data in the database later. :) */

        $("#mod_search").modal('hide');

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you are trying to do correctly, in the page that is called when you click 'Add' - I presume this is the original page, image 2 - before displaying the page you need the following in your php:

```
if(isset($_POST['member_select']){

    $items=$_POST['member_select'];
    foreach($items AS $id){
        /*  do the following with your chosen SQL DB approach 
           (I would recommend looking at PDO):*/
        INSERT INTO `event_attendees` (name, specialism) 
            SELECT name, specialism FROM `personal_profile` WHERE `id`= $id
    }
}
```

with error checking etc.

A slightly more efficient alternative would be:

```
if(isset($_POST['member_select']){

    $items=$_POST['member_select'];
    $list='';
    foreach($items AS $id) $list.=$id.',';
    rtrim($list,',');
    /*  do the following with your chosen SQL DB approach 
        (I would recommend looking at PDO):*/
    INSERT INTO `event_attendees` (name, specialism) 
          SELECT name, specialism FROM `personal_profile` WHERE `id` IN ($list)          
}
```

Comment: I don't want to save it on database yet. Just add it on table first. Anyway, I already got it. :)

Comment: @janie if you have an answer you should post your own answer and then accept it.  This will help other people who have your same original question, as they will be able to see how you solved it.